# EEGLAB failing to export .edf files

Tags: export, eeglab, european-data-format

I am trying to export a .set file to an .edf through EEGLAB but the files aren't saving as .edf files, rather, they're just saving as regular files. Does anyone know another way to export files from eeglab other than through the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work

```
pop_writeeeg(EEG, 'filepath_and_filename', 'TYPE','EDF');
```